# I have build an application with streamlit and I try to deploy it on the community cloud of streamlit with a new domain name bought. How can I do it?

Tags: streamlit

I have build an application with streamlit and I try to deploy it on the community cloud of streamlit with a new domain name bought. How can I do it ?

I try to deploy the streamlit application on streamlit community cloud with a new domain name bought